# can use induction or limits

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = {1 \ \over n+1} +{1 \ \over n+2}+ \ldots\ +{1 \ \over 2n}. $
Prove that for $ n \ge\ 3 $ one has  $ a_{n+1}\ge\ a_n $. and based on this conclude that $ {a_{2019}}>{3 \over 5}$